# Populate Zeros into df Where Organisms Were not Counted - R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a df, as shown below, that has raw counts of a species (3 unique focal species) per site and date. However the df does not include sites when no organisms were encountered. I have a second df that  has all the dates for each site visit. I need to populate zeros across the data frame for when sites were visited but no organism for each of the 3 species were not observed.

For example, site "admin_pond" was visited 4 times but when I pivot the data wider for one species it shows it only had 3 visits because 3 out of the 4 times organisms were encountered. I need to populate that 4th visit as a zero accordlingly.

[image: one species]

[image: true visits]

data for sites where organisms were encountered

```
mid_clean_up <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19116, 19116, 19116, 19117, 
19117, 19117, 19123, 19123, 19123, 19124, 19124, 19130, 19130, 
19130, 19131, 19131, 19132, 19138, 19138, 19139, 19139, 19146, 
19146, 19147, 19147, 19150, 19150, 19151, 19151, 19157, 19157, 
19158, 19158, 19166, 19170, 19170, 19171, 19171, 19184, 19184, 
19185, 19185, 19191, 19191, 19192, 19192, 19206, 19244, 19244, 
19245, 19265, 19265), class = "Date"), site = c("wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "phelps_pond", "phelps_pond", 
"phelps_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", "rv_pond", 
"rv_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", 
"admin_pond", "admin_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "phelps_pond", "phelps_pond", 
"phelps_pond", "phelps_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", 
"rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tryon_weber", "vorisek_pond", "vorisek_pond", "vorisek_pond", 
"vorisek_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tryon_weber", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond"), species_capture = c("pseudacris_crucifer", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "pseudacris_crucifer", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "pseudacris_crucifer", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "pseudacris_crucifer", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "pseudacris_crucifer", "rana_catesbeiana", 
"rana_clamitans", "pseudacris_crucifer", "rana_catesbeiana", 
"pseudacris_crucifer", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", 
"rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", 
"rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", 
"rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_clamitans", 
"rana_catesbeiana", "rana_clamitans", "rana_catesbeiana", "rana_catesbeiana", 
"rana_clamitans"), n = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 
16L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 20L, 1L, 4L, 22L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 
6L, 16L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 15L, 19L, 22L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 8L, 13L, 
1L, 13L, 7L, 29L, 3L, 39L, 3L, 31L, 2L, 2L, 29L, 1L, 11L, 20L, 
2L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))


# pivot table for visits for one species
bull_frog_visits <- mid_clean_up %>% 
  select(site, date, species_capture, n) %>% 
  filter(species_capture == "rana_catesbeiana") %>% 
  select(!species_capture) %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(n_visit = match(date, unique(date)),
         n_visit = paste0("visit_", n_visit, sep = "")) %>% 
  select(!date) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("n_visit"), values_from = c("n"))%>% 
  #add_row(site = "phelps_pond", capture_type = "recapture") %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("visit"), 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.) &
                          !is.na(lag(.)), 0, .)))
```

All sites Visited data

```
raw_visits <- structure(list(site = c("wood_lab_pond", "phelps_pond", "admin_pond", 
"rv_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", "admin_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "phelps_pond", "phelps_pond", 
"phelps_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "tryon_weber", "tryon_weber", "tryon_weber", "vorisek_pond", 
"vorisek_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tryon_weber", "tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond"), date = structure(c(19116, 
19117, 19123, 19124, 19130, 19131, 19132, 19138, 19139, 19140, 
19146, 19147, 19148, 19150, 19151, 19157, 19158, 19159, 19165, 
19166, 19166, 19170, 19171, 19184, 19185, 19191, 19192, 19206, 
19244, 19245, 19265), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will take all the site visits, connect them to the observed species records, and complete the list to include all the species, using n = 0 for those which were missing.

```
raw_visits %>%
  left_join(mid_clean_up) %>%
  complete(nesting(date, site), 
           species_capture = unique(mid_clean_up$species_capture), 
           fill = list(n = 0))
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(site, date)`
# A tibble: 95 × 4
   date       site          species_capture         n
   <date>     <chr>         <chr>               <int>
 1 2022-05-04 wood_lab_pond pseudacris_crucifer     2
 2 2022-05-04 wood_lab_pond rana_catesbeiana        2
 3 2022-05-04 wood_lab_pond rana_clamitans          1
 4 2022-05-05 phelps_pond   pseudacris_crucifer     4
 5 2022-05-05 phelps_pond   rana_catesbeiana        4
 6 2022-05-05 phelps_pond   rana_clamitans          7
 7 2022-05-11 admin_pond    pseudacris_crucifer     4
 8 2022-05-11 admin_pond    rana_catesbeiana        9
 9 2022-05-11 admin_pond    rana_clamitans          5
10 2022-05-12 rv_pond       pseudacris_crucifer    16
# ℹ 85 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move

```
  filter(species_capture == "rana_catesbeiana") %>% 
  select(!species_capture)
```

to the end of its call-flow. That is,

```
bull_frog_visits <- mid_clean_up %>%
  select(site, date, species_capture, n)  %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(n_visit = match(date, unique(date)),
         n_visit = paste0("visit_", n_visit, sep = "")) %>% 
  select(!date) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("n_visit"), 
              values_from = c("n"),
              values_fn = ~ ifelse(is.na(.),0,.)) %>% 
  #add_row(site = "phelps_pond", capture_type = "recapture") %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("visit"), 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.) &
                          !is.na(lag(.)), 0, .)))%>% 
  filter(species_capture == "rana_catesbeiana") %>% 
  select(!species_capture)
```

This produces the (hopefully desired) output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   site [6]
  site          visit_1 visit_2 visit_3 visit_4 visit_5 visit_6
  <chr>           <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>
1 wood_lab_pond       2       4       3      NA      NA      NA
2 phelps_pond         4       3       6      NA      NA      NA
3 admin_pond          9      15      20       0      NA      NA
4 rv_pond             1       7       5      13      29      11
5 tuttle_pond        15      22      39      31      29      20
6 vorisek_pond       14      13      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: That only populates for one site but not the other sites and is not in chronological order by visit for populating the zero